# Variable drawn from a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

What exactly is the meaning of a "variable drawn from a normal distribution"? I know what a normal distribution is, but my main exposure to "variables" is from calculus, so I have a hard time understanding this terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that this is a random variable (i.e.a measurable function defined on a probability space) whose distribution is the normal distribution.